# Adding records based on value from other records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm going to try this again because I'm so lost..: I have an Access database and the backend contains the tables:
tblStat

| groupID | Userid | complex | open | new account | Shipped | not-shipped | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | Yes | No | Yes |  |  | 869 |
| B | 147 | No | Yes | no |  |  | 936 |

And tblCode

| uniqueid | codetype | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A,yes,No,Yes | shipped | 869 |
| B,No,Yes,No | not-Shipped | 936 |

When I upload a report, it populates the tblStats and using the groupid, complex, open and new account records to make a uniqueid and later adds the code to tblStats. Based on the uniqueID, it can be shipped or not-shipped. The old reports we used contained shipped or not-shipped number values, but with the new reports, I will need to use codetype and code record to reference the tblStat for each order and determine whether the order is shipped or not, and add 1 to tblStats.

I want to do something like

`if tblCode.codetype = shipped and the code are the same then tblStat.shipped = 1 else if tblCode.Codetype = not-shipped and the codes are the same tblStat.not-shipped = 1`
and then:

`with recordset .shipped = shipped .not-shipped = notshipped end with`

I just can't seem to figure it out..

I really hope I've provided enough info and cleraity this time around. If you need any code, let me know. thanks.

Comment: I didn't find a question in your text. Could you show what are you trying to do and what is going wrong?

Comment: My bad.. I want to do something like:
`sudocode
if tblCode.code type = shipped then
tblStat.shipped = 1
else
if tblCode.Codetype = not-shipped
tblStat.not-shipped = 1`
the only thing is I an't figure out how to go about it..

Comment: Are the *complex, open, new account* text fields or boolean formatted to yes/no?

Comment: They are text fields. I need to change the info, due to sensitivity, but it's pretty much the same

Comment: edited, thats what i get for speed typing!

Comment: Is the code column unique in either table?

Comment: The code field's values in both the tables looks same but then I realized the numbers are different. Are these really different, or you made mistake while writing here?

Comment: I'm sorry but I made a mistake. The code number are the same in both tables

Comment: @kaligirl Then please edit the question to correct the numbers.

Comment: Two fields (shipped, not-shipped) doesn't seem necessary. Why not one field with 2 value options? Why even duplicate this data in two tables?

Comment: Not my disign and I can't change it. This is the same question you had issue with yesterday and i just took some time to fix.

Comment: Yes, I remember it. This one is more understandable. Schema just doesn't follow normalization principles.

Comment: Believe me, I wish I could change it too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant get my head around for a solution purely in SQL, but in VBA, the method below does the following:

1. Gather records due to be updated from tblStat.
2. Loop and try to find a match in tblCode.
3. Update record accordingly.

There's a helper function to try to find the match in tblCode and an `enum` the function returns to make the code a bit cleaner and easier to read.

I'm pretty sure something better exists.

```
Private Enum ShipEnum
    None = 0
    Shipped
    NotShipped
End Enum
```

---

```
Sub T()
    On Error GoTo catch
    
    'get records due to be updated
    Dim r As DAO.Recordset
    Set r = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT groupID, complex, [open], [new account], Shipped, [not-shipped], code FROM tblStat WHERE Shipped Is Null AND [not-shipped] Is Null;", dbOpenDynaset)
    If r.EOF Then
        MsgBox "No records."
        GoTo Leave
    End If
    
    r.MoveLast
    r.MoveFirst
    
    'loop and try to match each record with a record in tblCode
    Dim idx As Long, uniqueId As String, shippedStatus As ShipEnum
    For idx = 1 To r.RecordCount
    
        'build the unique id for the record
        uniqueId = r![groupID] & "," & r![Complex] & "," & r![Open] & "," & r![new account]
        
        'get codetype
        shippedStatus = CodeTypeByCriteria(uniqueId, r![Code])
        
        'update if shipped or not-shipped
        If shippedStatus <> ShipEnum.None Then
            r.Edit
            r![Shipped] = IIf(shippedStatus = ShipEnum.Shipped, 1, 0)
            r![not-shipped] = IIf(shippedStatus = ShipEnum.NotShipped, 1, 0)
            r.Update
        End If
        
        r.MoveNext
    Next idx
    
    'all good
    MsgBox "Complete"
    
Leave:
    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Close
    Exit Sub
    
catch:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function CodeTypeByCriteria(ByVal stringUniqueId As String, ByVal stringCode As String) As ShipEnum
    With CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT codetype FROM tblCode WHERE StrConv(uniqueId, 2)='" & StrConv(stringUniqueId, vbLowerCase) & "' And code='" & stringCode & "'", dbOpenSnapshot)
        If Not .EOF Then
            Select Case ![codetype]
                Case "shipped":
                    CodeTypeByCriteria = ShipEnum.Shipped
                    
                Case "not-shipped":
                    CodeTypeByCriteria = ShipEnum.NotShipped
                    
                Case Else:
                    Exit Function
            End Select
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Then edit your question to correct the table.

Comment: Is it possibe to do a DLookup with the backend DB? Only because it errors out due to the table being in the backend..

Comment: The front end is only a bunch of forms. the backend is where all the tables are stored. I guess they are linked in a way, but not enough to have a dlookup to tblcode

Comment: With `Set backendDB = openbackend(backendPath, False, False... `in the main form once the frontend is open to upload and view records from backend. then depending on what info is to be viewed, `aValue = backendDB.openrecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl..")` does that help?

Comment: Yeah, the backenddb is just a dao.database. You need to create a new access app and open the backend to do the lookup. Not very efficient. I'll update the answer to open a recordset instead of dlookup so you can use the backenddb reference.

Answer (score 1):

If code column in both the tables have unique values and you haven't made mistake while writing code field's values for both tables in your question then these queries should work:

```sql
UPDATE tblStat JOIN tblCode ON tblStat.code = tblCode.code
SET shipped = 1
WHERE CONCAT(groupID, ',', complex, ',', open, ',', new_account) = uniqueid
    AND codetype = 'shipped';

UPDATE tblStat JOIN tblCode ON tblStat.code = tblCode.code
SET not_shipped = 1
WHERE CONCAT(groupID, ',', complex, ',', open, ',', new_account) = uniqueid
    AND codetype = 'not-shipped';
```

**Edit:**
These queries are according to MySQL. In VBA, there should be some other function or way - like joining string with `+` operator?

Comment: I don't think MS Access has a `CONCAT` method, but it could be translated into a VBA function.

Comment: @KostasK. I don't know presently much about VBA, I had used it 2 years ago. I constructed the query according to MySQL. In VBA, there should be some other function or way like joining string with "+" operator?

Comment: Ampersand or + will concatenate strings in Access. If + is used to concatenate 2 fields or variables and one is Null then the result will be Null whereas ampersand will ignore Null and return the other string.

Comment: However, concatenation may not be necessary if both tables have uniqueid field, as indicated in a comment.